# How to remove Point Clouds obtained after processing from the initial Point Cloud in Open3D

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

So, I have imported a point cloud say `pcd` and after certain processing I have obtained two different point clouds `ceiling` and `floor`, both are part of original point clouds. Now, I have to obtain the remaining point cloud for exporting. How can I achieve that using Open3D?

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
geometry_left = pcd.select_by_index(floor, invert=True)
geometry_left = geometry_left.select_by_index(ceiling, invert=True)
```

However, this is obviously wrong because the first parameter of the function is not supposed to be `Point Cloud`, but a list of indices. How can I obtain this list of indices? I am very new to Open3D, so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to keep track of the indices during processing. However, now you can get them using the following syntax:

```
indices = np.where(np.isin(np.asarray(pcd.points), np.asarray(ceiling.points)))
```